# Evaluating a surface integral of a paraboloid

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surfaces, parametric

Calculate the average value of $(1+4z)^{3}$ on the surface of the paraboloid $z=x^{2}+y^{2}$,$x^{2}+y^{2} \leq 1$

---

I'm not sure on how to start this problem. I have already found the area of the paraboloid which is:

$A = \displaystyle\frac{\pi(5\sqrt{5}-1)}{6}$

However, when now dealing with the surface integral, I'm not sure on how to start as I have that $(1+4z)^{3}$ term. Normally, the way to carry out the integration would have been doing it in the projected region in the xy-plane and then transform to polar coordinates, but as I have a $z$ term I'm not sure on what to do (not specified if it was $f(x,y)$ or anything of the like). I was as well considering parametrizing the paraboloid with cylindrical coordinates, but in this case the range of the bounds are from $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ and $0 \leq r \leq 1$. What should I do in this case?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: $$Average=\frac{\iint_S (1+4z)^3\sqrt{\left({\partial z \over \partial x}\right)^2+\left({\partial z \over \partial y}\right)^2+1}\, \,  dx\, dy }{\iint_S\sqrt{\left({\partial z \over \partial x}\right)^2+\left({\partial z \over \partial y}\right)^2+1}\, \,  dx\, dy }=42+\frac{5\sqrt5}3$$

Answer (score 1):

Cylindrical coordinates look good, since $z = x^2 + y^2 = r^2$.  The integral looks like
$$
\iint_S \left( 1 + 4z \right)^3 \; dx \; dy = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \left( 1 + 4r^2 \right)^3 r \; dr \; d\theta,
$$
which can be computed with a substitution.

Comment: ah. very good.+1

Comment: @
Sammy shouldn't it be $\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \left( 1 + 4r^2 \right)^{5/2}
 r \; dr \; d\theta,$ ??

Comment: Why the $\frac{5}{2}$ exponent?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, why in this case would $z$ turn into $r^{2}$? That's what I don't really understand. Or is it because our surface is given by $S: x = r\cos\theta, y = r\sin\theta$ and $z = x^{2} + y^{2} = r^{2}$? I don't really understand how surface integrals work.

Comment: On the paraboloid, $z = x^2 + y^2 = r^2$.  In other words, the surface is the simply the parabola $z = r^2$ in the $(r, z)$ plane, rotated about the $z$-axis.  Since your integrand function depends only on $z$, you can replace it with $r^2$.

Comment: This doesn't seem correct to me. Don't you neen some kind of factor in front of $rdrd\theta$ for the surface integral? For example, I would expect $(1+4r^2)^3\sqrt{1+4r^2}r dr d\theta$